# Pattern matching in the end of a string (postgres)

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

Let's say I have the following table (called filetable) with file names:

```
file
something.h
something.cc
somethingelse.js
something.py
something.xkh
something.jpeg
```

I tried the following query:

```
select file 
  from filetable
    where file ~ E'\.[cc|h|js|py]';
```

The query output is:

```
file
something.h
something.cc
somethingelse.js
something.py
something.xkh
something.jpeg
```

However, I only need files that finish exactly with .cc , .h , .js , .py.
How to improve this query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This regex:

```
\.[cc|h|js|py]
```

doesn't do what you think it does. `[]` is a character class so `[cc|h|js|py]` matches the *characters* `'c'`, `'h'`, `'j'`, `'p'`, `'s'`, `'y'`, and `'|'` rather than the four extensions that you want to match. If you want to match those four extensions then you want to use parentheses to group your alternations:

```
\.(cc|h|js|py)
```

You're also not anchoring your regex so it will match things `'pancakes.html'` when you don't want it to. You can fix that by adding an `$` to anchor the pattern to the end of the string:

```
\.(cc|h|js|py)$
```

And your string doesn't contain any C-style escape sequences (such as `\n`) so you don't need the `E` prefix:

```
where file ~ '\.(cc|h|js|py)$'
```